# How to show event message in Azure Service Fabric Explorer

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I'm new to Azure Service Fabric. I follow the tutorial to create hello demo service for Stateless.
It's simple service and I can find the Event Message in local VS IDE Diagnostic Events to show the message that I print

```
ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(this.Context, "Working-{0}", ++iterations);
```

Like below picture:
[image]

But I can't see any log for cluster manager explorer.
[image]

Is it possible to show the event log in this explorer? How to do it?
There are my demo event source class code;

```
[NonEvent]
public void Message(string message, params object[] args)
{
    if (this.IsEnabled())
    {
        string finalMessage = string.Format(message, args);
        Message(finalMessage);
    }
}

private const int MessageEventId = 1;
[Event(MessageEventId, Level = EventLevel.Informational, Message = "{0}")]
public void Message(string message)
{
    if (this.IsEnabled())
    {
        WriteEvent(MessageEventId, message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running this on Azure? As of Service Fabric version 6.4. the EventStore APIs are only available for Windows clusters running on Azure only.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure that currently the Service Fabric Explorer (SFX) only shows node level events and not application specific events.

According to the resent 7.0 release announcement (https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-Service-Fabric/Service-Fabric-7-0-Release/ba-p/1015482) work is ongoing to display application specific events in SFX